# Basement ceiling

Tags: drywall, insulation, moisture, basement-refinishing

I'm finishing my 50 year old basement and need advice regarding the 6'x4' ceiling area (which is actually a cement slab from the front porch). It drops down 2" lower than the rest of the ceiling.  The rest of the basement only has 6'9" clearance so lowering the main ceiling to match this area is out of the question.

Would you seal this or just install a thermal barrier? And what kind of barrier?  Any suggestions on how to attach the barrier and the drywall?  I'm trying to avoid drilling into the cement as much as possible.

I hope this is now concise enough to meet forum rules.

Thanks in advance.
[image: picture of basement ceiling/slab]
[image: view from stairs]

Comment: #2 you might consider doing a drop ceiling, on #4 I would try to find a way not to frame against the stair, otherwise you'll have to frame all the way up or have a wall protruding out.

Comment: I would postpone any covering on the concrete until spring and you are sure the water leaking issue is taken care of.   Point #4 should be a separate question, and more details added.  Attach header ???

Comment: @AlaskaMan I moved the framing question to a new post.  I supposed I could leave this one area unfinished and get the rest done now.  (my parents passed away and I have to clear out their house and many items will be moved into my place so I need to keep moving forward)

Comment: @RoniLloyd Presumably you are not going to be storing your parents things on the stair landing under the concrete ceiling and you could still  move forward  with the rest and cover it at a later time. I think it best to be sure of the water issue.